# How do I set up calculator functions for multiple operations?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
let reset = document.getElementById("reset"),
    output = document.getElementById("output"),
    calcButtons = document.getElementById("calc_buttons");

function clearScreen() {
  output.innerHTML = " "
}

calcButtons.addEventListener("click", printNum, false);

function printNum(e) {
  if (e.target !== e.currentTarget) {
    let clickedItem = e.target.value;
    output.innerHTML += clickedItem;
  };


}

function add(){

};

function subtract(){

};

function multiply(){

};

function divide(){

};
```

```html
  <h1> My First JavaScript Calculator </h2>
  <div id="calculator">

  <div id="calc_buttons">
    <span id="output"></span>

    <button onclick="clearScreen()"class="operate" id="reset">C</button>

    <button class="num" id="seven" value="7">7</button>
    <button class="num" id="eight" value="8">8</button>
    <button class="num" id="nine" value="9">9</button>

    <button class="operate" id="divide" value="/">/</button>

    <button class="num" id="four" value="4">4</button>
    <button class="num" id="five" value="5">5</button>
    <button class="num" id="six" value="6">6</button>

    <button class="operate" id="multiply" value="*">*</button>

    <button class="num" id="one" value="1">1</button>
    <button class="num" id="two" value="2">2</button>
    <button class="num" id="three" value="3">3</button>

    <button class="operate" id="minus" value="-">-</button>

    <button class="num" id="zero" value="0">0</button>

   <button class="operate" id="decimal" value=".">.</button>
   <button class="operate" id="equals" value="=">=</button>

   <button class="operate" id="plus" value="+">+</button>
</div>
```

How would I set up a functions for multiple operations in a calculator application?

I have most of the calculator finished aside from the actual 'calculation' portion of it. Which is kind of the main point of a calculator. This one is escaping me. Does anyone have any ideas on how to approach this issue? I'd appreciate some in-depth explanation as well.

Comment: There are millions of questions about calculators, many with complete or almost complete code. Have you read any of them?

Comment: I saw your other questions, why didn't you validate or comment on any answer? It is hardly engaging to spend time answering you!

Comment: I'm new to the site. Every time I tried to leave a comment to thank someone it never worked for some reason.

Comment: you have first to validate answer, then you get reputation points, and then you can post comments, read https://stackoverflow.com/tour and follow  links

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval